# Linux: Check if in Same Network

Tags: bash, ip, substring

I want to test in a bash-script if two IPs are on the same network.

I have a IP `$remoteIP` and I want to test if it is on the same network (local area network) as my current machine (So for example `$remoteIP` = `192.168.2.200` and `hostname -I` = `192.168.2.13` with a subnet mask of for example `255.255.255.0` these hosts are on the same network. A host with 192.168.1.32 will not be on the same network.)

I want to do that because I want to check if I ssh'ed  on a computer on my local network or on some server with a direct IP. Based on that I want to color the ps1-prompt (Green = No ssh, Yellow = Local Network, Red = Online Server)

At first, I only need to support the big Subnet masks (255.0.0.0, 255.255.0.0, 255.255.255.0).

So I need the following steps:

1. Get Subnet Mask of Interface where the ssh-connection comes in
2. Test What subnet mask it is (simple if [ ... ] )
3. Get the IP address over that the ssh-connection comes in
4. Get the remoteIP address (I think it will be in some environment variable)
5. Substring the two adresses based on subnet mask
6. Compare network parts.

At point 1, 3 and 5 I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: I know that it's not your answer, bug `ping -t 1 $remoteIP` should fail when not in the same network

Comment: But if it doesn't fail it isn't shure if it is in the same network ;-) I am just shure that I can reach the server over some other neworks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternate strategy would be to use Linux's `ip` command to determine what your default gateway is and if a given IP address will be routed via said gateway.

The default gateway can be seen in the output of `ip route`:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2
```

To get just the default gateway's IP address:

```
$ ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3}'
192.168.1.1
```

To determine how a given IP address will be routed use `ip route get`:

```
$ ip route get 4.2.2.2
4.2.2.2 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.2

$ ip route get 192.168.1.10
192.168.1.10 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.2
```

(Note that the first command says "`via 192.168.1.1`" indicating that it will be routed via the default gateway)

Putting everything together in to a function:

```
is_remote_ip() {
   ip route get $1 | grep -q "via $(ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3}') "
}
```

Demonstration:

```
$ is_remote_ip 4.2.2.2 && echo yes || echo no
yes

$ is_remote_ip 192.168.1.10 && echo yes || echo no
no
```

Comment: Good starting point, but my server for example doesn't Print a "via"